# OptiFine Cape Custom Color Background?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-optifine

I bought an OptiFine cape few months ago and I saw a player wearing an OptiFine cape with custom (black - #000000) background with white skull symbol.

How? I checked NameMC and it is an OptiFine cape (not lunar client cape). I will not share the actual player name, if it's not needed.

[image: OptiFine cape]

[image]

As you can see from the images, the background of that background is completely black but I think OptiFine doesn't allow custom colors. Am I wrong? Please correct me and if you know how to achieve this or a similar cape, I would be happy if you could share it with me.

Comment: It might be purely coincidence (and this thread may be pretty old) , but I think I found [the player you mentioned in your post has posted a question themself](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/406065/optifine-cape-white-wall-on-a-black-background) (related to the OptiFine cape). I saw the post and immediately thought of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No

OptiFine doesn't support RGB color values for banner capes; you can only use the Minecraft dye colors provided.

It is technically true for regular `OF` capes, but only with a color picker.

Comment: Well, then how did it that player as he doesn't have any "OF" text on his cape.

Comment: It could be the color resolution of your monitor. Sometimes certain screens will show colors a bit differently.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you.